# Index in plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I plotted the following data in R

```
data$cm
 [1] 55.5 68.0 65.0 67.7 70.0 66.0 60.0 62.0 52.0 50.0 62.0 16.0 15.0 17.0 16.0 17.0 17.0
```

Using the `plot` function.

```
plot(data$cm ,type = "l",col="red", ylab="(cm)", lwd=2, font.lab=2, main="Comparison",
     cex.axis = 1.5,cex.lab = 1.5,font=2, cex.main=1.5)
```

I get the following plot 
[image]

but I am wondering, what does "index" means?

Comment: When you plot just a vector of data (one axis only), it auto-generates the x-axis (`seq_along(x)`, implemented by `xy.coords(..)` which is called by `plot.default`) and labels it "Index" to remind you that the x-axis is the index from the vector you provided.

Answer (score -1):

An index is a sequence starting from 1.